# UIDocumentMenuViewController initWithDocumentTypes:inMode: can only be called with mode Import or Open

Tags: ios, crash, uikit, icloud-documents

In my iOS app I'm opening a `UIDocumentMenuViewController`. When I called it with the `UIDocumentPickerModeImport` mode, everything works fine (all my iCloud entitlements are set up).

When I call it with the `UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService`, however, the app crashes with this error:

> Assertion failure in -[UIDocumentMenuViewController initWithDocumentTypes:inMode:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.6.22/UIDocumentMenuViewController.m:71
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIDocumentMenuViewController initWithDocumentTypes:inMode:] can only be called with mode Import or Open'

What am I doing wrong? Why can this only be called with the Import or Open modes?

My code:

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *exportMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.image"]
                                                                                                    inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService];
    
exportMenu.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:exportMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This happens in the simulator and on two devices that I've tested (both running iOS 10).

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found the answer: When wanting to **export** you need to use a different init method: `initWithURL:inMode:`

I wish the exception would be a little bit more helpful in this case :)