# "-[UIDocumentPickerViewController initWithDocumentTypes:inMode:] can only be called with mode Import or Open"

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm trying enable export of data out of my SwiftUI app by allowing the user to select a location in their Files app to place the exported zip. I'm running into this error the moment I try to the `DocumentPickerView`. I've looked at [UIDocumentMenuViewController initWithDocumentTypes:inMode: can only be called with mode Import or Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989567/uidocumentmenuviewcontroller-initwithdocumenttypesinmode-can-only-be-called-wi) but even with his accepted answer, I can't seem to sort out how to adjust my syntax to comply with the modified `init`

Here's my code:

```
struct DocumentPickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let completion: (URL) -> Void
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPickerView>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let exportPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeZipArchive as String], in: .exportToService)
        exportPicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        exportPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        return exportPicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPickerView>) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> DocumentPickerCoordinator {
        return DocumentPickerCoordinator(completion: completion)
    }
}

class DocumentPickerCoordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    let completion: (URL) -> Void
    
    init(completion: @escaping (URL) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
    }
    
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard let exportURL = urls.first else {
            print("No URL selected for export")
            return
        }
        
        completion(exportURL)
    }
}
```

And my export function look like this:

```
    func exportDataAsZip(to url: URL) {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        
        // Creating a ZIP archive
        guard SSZipArchive.createZipFile(atPath: url.path, withContentsOfDirectory: documentsDirectory.path) else {
            print("Failed to create ZIP archive")
            return
        }
        
        // Exporting images from Core Data
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let managedObjectContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CapturedImage> = CapturedImage.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let images = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for image in images {
                if let imageData = image.image, let timestamp = image.timestamp {
                    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
                    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: timestamp)
                    let imageUrl = url.appendingPathComponent("\(dateString).jpg")
                    try imageData.write(to: imageUrl)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to fetch images from Core Data")
            return
        }
        
        // Adding images to the ZIP archive
        let imageUrls = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        for imageUrl in imageUrls {
            if imageUrl.pathExtension == "jpg" {
                let success = SSZipArchive.createZipFile(atPath: url.path, withFilesAtPaths: [imageUrl.path])
                if !success {
                    print("Failed to add image to ZIP archive")
                }
            }
        }
        
        print("Exported data to: \(url.path)")
    }
}
```

I'm calling the view with a `sheet` modifier:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingExportSheet, onDismiss: nil, content: {
    DocumentPickerView(completion: { url in
        exportDataAsZip(to: url)
    })
})
```

Appreciate any input!

Comment: you forgot to set the completion property on the coordinator in `updateUIViewController`. And you can remove passing it into the coordinator's init in makeCoordinator because that is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wish to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` for export, you need to use the `init(forExporting:)` or `init(forExporting:asCopy:)` initializers. If you need to support iOS 13 or earlier, then you use `init(url:in:)` or `init(urls:in:)`.

The older initializer `init(documentTypes:in:)` is only used for import, not export.

Your whole setup is kind of backwards. Your code is currently there to select a file and call a completion callback with the selected URL. That setup is for an import. For an export, you need to start with the URL of the file you are exporting and then create the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` with the URL you wish to export. You don't need a completion block with a URL.

Answer (score 0):

To export in SwiftUI you can use [fileExporter(isPresented:document:contentType:defaultFilename:onCompletion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fileexporter(ispresented:document:contenttype:defaultfilename:oncompletion:)-32vwk)